# Looking for a custom font based ubuntu note taking app

Tags: fonts

I've recently moved to linux from windows. I've installed ubuntu and using for a few weeks. I do blogging in my native language(bangla). The problem is almost all the note taking apps available in ubuntu comes with default fonts.They dont even have font changing options. I want to set my own custom fonts to the note app I will be using. So can you suggest an ubuntu note taking app which can be configured with custom fonts? any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of notes are you talking about? Typed or hand-written? If you're looking for typed notes, doesn't LibreOffice satisfy your needs?

Comment: its actually hand-written blogs written in bangla language. I used to write in evernote in windows. so I was looking for similar apps in ubuntu. The similar apps doesnt have the custom fonts support. I have tried joplin, standard notes, notes from snapcraft. I just wanna know if any of these type app can have custom font support. I am not using libre office mainly for UI reasons.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/evernote/?p=14&platform=linux

Answer (score 1):

You can use Zim. It's a note taking app that is found in Ubuntu's repository as well. To install it, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install zim
```

Here is a sample text written in Zim:

[image: sample text written in Zim]

And here is where you can change the font from the *Preferences* menu (*Use a custom font* checkbox):

[image: change font preferences]